# Magento: Manage Categories->Display Settings

Tags: magento

Im trying to add a new attribute in the Manage Categories->Display Settings. I just want to know if what table does the Display Settings saves it data. im kinda new to magento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento uses a EAV (extended attribute value) table structure for the data around categories, customers, and products. This is a very powerful, yet complex structure.

The main tables that category data is saved to are:

```
catalog_category_entity
catalog_category_entity_datetime
catalog_category_entity_decimal
catalog_category_entity_int
catalog_category_entity_text
catalog_category_entity_varchar
```

The basic category data is stored in `catalog_category_entity`. All of the integer values, for example, are stored in `catalog_category_entity_int`.

To find out where the data is stored you need to run this query:

```
SELECT t1.attribute_id, t1.attribute_code, t1.backend_type
FROM eav_entity_type AS t0
INNER JOIN eav_attribute AS t1
  ON (t0.entity_type_id = t1.entity_type_id)
WHERE (t0.entity_model = "catalog/category")
```

When I run it I get this data:

[image: category attributes]

So to now get to the data for category name you would do this query:

```
SELECT t0.entity_id, t1.value
FROM catalog_category_entity AS t0
LEFT OUTER JOIN catalog_category_entity_varchar AS t1
  ON (((t1.attribute_id = 41) AND (t1.store_id = 0)) AND (t1.entity_id = t0.entity_id))
```

I bet you're glad you asked now.